# How can I get weblog:entries to return all values

Tags: ee1, entries, status

I have this code in a template:

```
<select id="field_id_43" name="field_id_43">
    <option value="" >No related Listing</option>
    {exp:weblog:entries weblog="listings" dynamic="no" status="not closed" orderby="title" sort="asc"} 
        <option value="{entry_id}" >{title}</option>
    {/exp:weblog:entries}
</select>
```

The number of items returned in the dropdown seems to be limited in some way in that the dropdown is only poputlated with listings from the letter "A" up to the letter "H".

How do I make sure that the dropdown returns ALL listings and not just a certain number of them. Where is this limit set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default number of entries returned by exp:weblog:entries is limited to 100. You can set a limit parameter to whatever you like and over-ride this limit.

```
{exp:weblog:entries weblog="listings" dynamic="no" status="not closed" orderby="title" sort="asc" limit="400"}
```

Be aware that there is a also chance you may run into memory and performance problems since EE will pull ALL the field data for each entry even though you are only displaying a single field.

You may be better off using a custom query, however, since you're using EE1 I'm not sure how you would do this.

Comment: +1.  EE1 support the 'disable' parameter mostly similar to EE2.  http://ee1docs.com/modules/weblog/parameters.html#par_disable  What's need here for performance is: `disable="categories|custom_fields|member_data|pagination|trackbacks"`